# Approval Process Assignment Email Alert Not Sending

Tags: approval-process, email-alert

I'm having difficulty figuring out why this approval process isn't sending an email to the approver. Here are the details on the process:

- Active: Yes
- Next Automated Approver Determined By: (this is empty)
- Entry Criteria: (this is empty)
- Approval Assignment Email Template: My_Approval_Assignment_Template
- Initial Submission Actions:

  - Record Lock
- Approval Steps

  - First - Criteria: Custom_Field__c EQUALS 'Required', else Approve, Assigned Approver: Assign to Approver__c
- Final Approval Actions

  - Record Lock
  - Email Alert: Notify Submitter
  - Field Update: Mark Approved
- Final Rejection Actions

  - Record Lock
  - Email Alert: Notify Submitter
  - Field Update: Mark Rejected

The problem is My_Approval_Assignemnt_Template doesn't get sent out to Approver__c in approval step 1. Here is what I have tried:

1. I have verified that the email address is valid.
2. I have verified that the user is actually assigned the approval process.
3. I have verified that the approval/rejection emails go out properly.
4. I have verified that email deliverability is 'all email.'
5. I have switched the submitter and approver users and the approval/rejection emails still behave as expected, but the assignment alert is still not sent.

Am I missing something? I saw [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BHExIAO) that they mention the 'next automated approver' should be filled out, but for my process I don't need that, I just need a specific calculated approver in the Approver__c lookup field on my object. Are those two fields tied together?

Comment: Is that Approver__c is the custom look up user field in your object?

Comment: That is correct. Approver__c is a user lookup.

Comment: Is that Initial submitter is Record Owner?

Comment: I have tried with the initial submitter being the record owner and not being the record owner.

Comment: Have you checked your org's email deliverability setting? (Setup -> type 'Email deliverability' in the quick search box) I believe that it needs to be set to `All` for these types of emails (approval, workflow, emails sent via Apex) to actually be sent.

Comment: Hi Derek, per my original post, yes, those are set to all.

Comment: @Cameron.Ames ah, missed that when I was skimming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is resolved. It was actually an error on the exchange side of things receiving email, even though other approvals are delivered. Testing with another email service such as gmail produces the expected results. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its workaround to try and see whether works for you.

---

Under Initial Submission Actions

- new action "Email Alert", add email template and other details
- select Recipient Type as "Related User", choose field "Approver_c"

---

In case if its not working, then try with other email id. 
Please post back your findings.

Comment: Hi Shakeel, I have tried this and it works. However I cannot use this because it will send an email to the approver even when the record does not meet the criteria in step 1. In that scenario, the approver should not receive an email because they don't need to approve anything.

Comment: @Cameron.Ames  you can put your Step1 criteria in the Initial Entry Criteria which is now blank

Comment: Hi Santanu, the reason I have not done that is that no email needs to go out if the record does not meet the conditions on the approval step.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this one without managing to find an answer that suits you - for me it wasn't working because email address of the submitter was not valid.

Alongside with standard stuff like:

- Making sure deliverability is on
- Email templates are set as 'Available for use'
- Approval process is active and steps do execute (test by adding field update next to your email alert)
- Email/Contact/User to whom email will be sent has a correct email
- Email isn't in spam folder

Make sure that the email address of the user that is going to be in the 'From:' field of the email alert message is valid (at least doesn't end with .mysandbox or something like that as it did in my case) and see if it works then.
Edit: a popular trick how to reuse the same mailbox by appending the plus sign tripped salesforce over I think (e.g. slavko+test1@mycompany.com).