# Approval Process Does Not Send Email Alert For Specific Profile

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I created an Approval Process for a custom object and added access to the Submit for Approval button on the page layout for a profile. When I'm logged in as Sys Admin, the process will send a bell notification and an email as expected.

However, when I log in under a custom profile that has been given access to the App, and I click the Submit for Approval button, the process sends the bell notification but it does NOT sent the email.

The profile has access to the App, custom object and fields, page layouts, and record types so what could be preventing the email from being sent?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this answer was correct. We were trying to send an email logged in as a user with invalid email, so when we set and confirmed a valid email it worked.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/346478/49988